# Add cell value from a matrix row based on corresponding index to another matrix row

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I have two arrays `A` and `B`.

Column 1 of array `A` contains the index number of the samples; other columns of matrix `A` contain other attributes of each sample, (in array `B`, the first two cell along each row contain an attribute and the index number of a sample).

Columns 2, 4 and 6 of array `B` contain the index number of samples contained in matrix `A`.

I am trying to insert corresponding sample attribute in column 4 of array `A` (based on corresponding index number in array `A` and `B`) into new 3rd, 6th and 9th column of matrix `B`; to have matrix `C` as shown below:

```
A = [1,3.43,2.34,5.43,3.22;2,8.32,6.34,7.34,2.34;3,3.67,8.34,8.23,1.34;4,2.67;6.89,4.99,8.65;5,1.33,5.42,2.53,6.13]     
B = [0.12,2,0.15,1,0.65,3;0.33,5,0.62,4,0.55,1;0.91,1,0.77,2,0.66,5]    
C = [0.12,2,7.34,0.15,1,5.43,0.65,3,1.34;0.33,5,2.53,0.62,4,4.99,0.55,1,5.43;0.91,1,5.43,0.77,2,7.34,0.66,5,2.53]
```

I have tried the following code but got an error:

```
for i = 1:3
    f = ismember(A(:,1(i)), B(:,2), 'rows');
    k = find(f);
    f = A(f,4);
    C = [C,f(i)]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a `typo` in your A matrix - different size of rows. Maybe you meant:

```
A = [1,3.43,2.34,5.43,3.22;
    2,8.32,6.34,7.34,2.34;
    3,3.67,8.34,8.23,1.34;
    4,2.67,6.89,4.99,8.65;
    5,1.33,5.42,2.53,6.13];

B = [ 0.12,2,0.15,1,0.65,3;
    0.33,5,0.62,4,0.55,1;
    0.91,1,0.77,2,0.66,5];
```

So if you run your code, you will have good numbers, but in bad order. You should try:

```
Z = [0;0;0];
C = [[B(:,1:2) Z B(:,3:4) Z B(:,5:6)]]; %Generating satic part
for j = 1:3 %generating dynamic part in loop
    for i = 1:3
        n = A(find(ismember(A(:,(1)), B(i,j*2), 'rows')),4);
        C(i,j*3) = n;
    end
end
```

The output is:

```
C =

    0.1200    2.0000    7.3400    0.1500    1.0000    5.4300    0.6500    3.0000    8.2300
    0.3300    5.0000    2.5300    0.6200    4.0000    4.9900    0.5500    1.0000    5.4300
    0.9100    1.0000    5.4300    0.7700    2.0000    7.3400    0.6600    5.0000    2.5300
```